# A question about the laplacian of homogeneous functions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, spherical-harmonics

I'm reading the following [document](http://www.ohiouniversityfaculty.com/mohlenka/research/uguide.pdf) trying to understand the basics of *spherical harmonics*.

Now, I understand that if we deal with *homogeneous functions* it's convenient to represent them in polar coordinates. In particular, using polar coords the *Laplacian* becomes:

$$\Delta_2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$$

So the Laplacian acts on homogeneous functions *separately* on $r$, $\theta$ (because there are no mixed terms, right?).

1. In $r$ it reduces the power by two. (I guess because the second term is the second order differential operator with respect to $r$, but then how do we take into account the last term $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ ?)
2. In $\theta$ it acts using the restriction of $\Delta_2$ to the circle, namely the *circular laplacian* $\Delta_{2S}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}$.

Is $\Delta_{2S}$ obtained by somehow considering only the first term of $\Delta_2$? Why by taking the second derivative with respect to $\theta$ we *restrict to the circle*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. As the computation in the link shows, it acts in $r$ by reducing the power twice (and multiplying by $n^2$), and it acts in $\theta$ by differentiating twice.

1. You lose two powers of $r$ when you take two derivatives of such homogeneous functions in $r$, and you lose two when you take one derivative then divide by $r$.
2. Yup. If you're on the circle, then radius is fixed. So, you only have angular changes.

Comment: Many thanks! So when we're considering the *restriction to the circle*, we are setting the other terms $=0$?

Comment: Indeed, since you are not varying $r$. Here's another way to think about it. If $\theta$ is your only variable, and  it is a real number ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$, then you should just be looking at the regular laplacian on the line.